# Excel VBA - Update a metadata table

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel tool, I have a GUI-Sheet which contains a metadata table for the sheets in the workbook. This metadata table has an update button which clears the table and re-reads the metadata.
Now, however, I have added columns, which contain information that I have entered by hand. This means I can't clear the table anymore for obvious reasons.

Excluding these columns from the clear isn't an option since the number of sheets and therefore the desired position of the information can vary.

The only solution I could come up with by myself was to create a temporary table, copying the hand-typed info and the corresponding sheet-names into it, clearing the table, re-reading the metadata and pasting the hand-typed info by searching for the sheet's name in the metadata table.

I thought however, there might be a more elegant solution I just couldn't see.

Columns 1-3 in the table shown below are added by hand

[image: The metadata table (excuse the German headers)]

Comment: You can need to store your "extra" information (anything which cannot be regenerated by your "refresh" routine) in a separate table, though it's not clear how you'd join the two together.  Some actual examples would be useful here.

Comment: @TimWilliams gotcha. Added part of the table in question. I would really like to avoid adding another table for the hand-typed info.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

unable to paste screenshot as comment hence mentioning it as an answer here. As commented by @Tim Williams, you need to keep the hand typed field out of table so, on refresh the data isn't lost.

Comment: If there is no way except my current solution and creating a second table, I might just stick to the temporary table I think. Cheers for the suggestion anyway!